# Merging a tensor of 3x10 to 1x10, what methods to use?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have made some model that in the end will output a tensor of 3 x 10. The reason why it's 3 x 10 is because the vocabulary size is 10, and there are 3 elements in a sequence (this is a sequence multilabel classification problem). This tensor will need to somehow be softmaxed to a 1x10 tensor. Can someone give me explanations about the methods that are available and maybe some example in Keras?

I saw some merging methods in Keras like average or add. Those can be useful in this case but those seems to need two or more tensors as the input. Therefore I probably need to split the 3 x 10 tensor to 3 tensors 1 x 10 each and average them. Maybe there are better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to achieve what you want is to use a final 1x1 Convolution layer.
A layer with 1×1 convolution kernel allow to merge your 3x10 tensor into a 1x10, and
simultaneously learns the fusion weight during training.

Add this layer :

```
   output = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='your_activation')(your_3x10_tensor)
```

Hope this is the solution you were looking for !

Comment: Is there any advantage using "dynamic" merging with weight like this over "static" merging like just adding/averaging the tensor element-wise?

Comment: Dynamic is usefull when each of the tensor you merge can have a different wight on the results, but if all of this tensors always have the same impact, you can do it staticaly